# Switch z-index between two angular arrays

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

The code is here
In my view I have

```
<div class="circle" ng-class="circleIndex ? 'zindex-on' : 'zindex-off'" ng-repeat="security in ySecurityData.securities" ng-style="{'bottom': security.totalHeight + '%'"></div>


<div ng-repeat="security in graphData.securities" class="badge-repeat"><span class="badge clearfix" ng-click="swapZindex($index)"><i class="pull-left"></i> <span class="pull-left">{{ security.name }}</span></span>
</div>
```

On the controller :

```
$scope.swapZindex = function(i) {
   $scope.circleIndex = true;
}
```

The Css is like:

```
.zindex-on {
    z-index: 9;
}

.zindex-off {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Using ng-click, how can I give `z-index` as `9` only to the corresponding circle(first array) based on the array index of the badge(second array)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a plunker example. I will be easy to resolve

Comment: @Sharmilla Here you have https://plnkr.co/edit/8l23Aoni9sU6ioZnVocn, sorry but I don't know how to add bootstrap to plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above answer was as per my assumption now as you provided plunker here is the improved plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZdmYuKSQwFfVeAQWGeLl?p=preview

Please looke after it

js code changed

```
$scope.swapZindex = function(i) {
if($scope.circleIndex[i]){
   $scope.circleIndex[i] =false
   }else{
      $scope.circleIndex[i] = true;
   }

}
```

html change

```
<div class="circle" ng-class="{'zindex-on': circleIndex[$index]  }"
ng-repeat="security in ySecurityData.securities">{{$index}}</div>
```

css change

```
.circle {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
position: static;
background: red;
border-radius: 50%;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: tnks, this should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from your question is that you have two ng-repeats when we click on second ng-repeat then same index of first ng-repeat should be added with class zindex-on

This sample working demo i made from your problem statement if i understood your problem wrong feel free to communicate

In your html

```
<div class="circle" ng-class="{'zindex-on': circleIndex[$index]  }"" ng-repeat="security in ySecurityData.securities" >{{circleIndex[$index]}}   {{security}}</div>


<div ng-repeat="security in graphData.securities" class="badge-repeat"><span class="badge clearfix" ng-click="swapZindex($index)"><i class="pull-left"></i> <span class="pull-left">{{ security }}</span></span>
```

In js

```
$scope.swapZindex = function(i) {
$scope.circleIndex[i] = true;
}
```

Only difference is way you used ng-class and inside function you didn't used index

here is working demo http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/oYrwEQ

No need of class zindex-off because once class zindex-on is not there by default z-index will be 0